# Bad Line Graphs

Tags: support, review, information-display, badge-progress

I noticed in Review that the progress line graph has a color and a line that don't match up, and then when you get the mouseover, neither lines up with the color on that progress bar:

[image: Bad Line Graph]

Can we get an exact explanation of what this is telling us?

Comment: That looks like it lines up pretty well, compared with the grey line…

Comment: I think the 2nd line graph looks right, the first one makes no sense.

Comment: The bar on the first line indicates the 250 mark. Isn't it?

Comment: I suppose that could be, write up a good answer on that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the top graph the first line shows how close you are to 250 for your [reviewer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1478/reviewer). The full bar shows how close you are to 1000 for the [Steward badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/2279/steward).

The bottom graph shows how close you are to the next badge, which is 250 for reviewer.

[image: Workign towards Reviewer]

Once you have your Reviewer badge the line will still be there on the top graph.

[image: Working towards Steward]

Answer (score 7):

#### Bar on the first line indicates the next milestone in review specific badges:

The line on the stats bar indicates the next milestone that a user could achieve in earning a review specific badge.

Below screenshot taken from my stats indicates that if I review *`250`* posts, I can achieve Reviewer badge and I have currently completed *`22`* out of the required *`250`* reviews. Bar indicates that 250 mark.

Hovering mouse over the stats indicates the details on how much I have achieved with respect to the milestone.

[image: Milestone indicator]

Comment: I want to give you a +1, but the arrow isn't freehand, so I don't know if I can do it.